# Numpy masking 3d array

Tags: numpy

I'm not sure how to achieve the following (preferably without a loop). 
I have a numpy array A having dimensions 100*100*3.

I also have a numpy array M having the same dimensions (100*100*3). M is actually a mask, and M[i,j] is [0,0,0] for most pairs (i,j) but for some pairs (i,j) it is not equal to [0,0,0].

What I would like to do is the following:

```
A[i,j] = M[i,j] when M[i,j] != [0,0,0]
```

`A[ M != [0,0,0]] = M [ M != [0,0,0]]` doesn't seem to work.

How can this be done efficiently with numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were needed to look for `ALL` match along the last axis and use that mask for `boolean-indexing/masking` -

```
mask = ~(M==0).all(-1) # or (M!=0).any(-1)
A[mask] = M[mask]
```

Or use `np.where` -

```
mask = ~(M==0).all(-1,keepdims=1)
Aout = np.where(mask, M, A)
```